# Stop transition when collapsing

Tags: css

Once navigation bar is not collapsed, submenu is shown and user collapses navigation bar it still shows transition for submenu which I don't want. I tried removing transition when navbar is not closed which did not help. Also tried to remove the transition completely but this I dont want as I want a transition for submenu when the navigation bar is collapsed. Im new to CSS so tried my best but still couldn't figure it out.

PS: To see the navbar correctly please, run the snippet on full page.

Thanks in advance for help!

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const collapsed = 'false';
    
    $('.navLinks').each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('navbar2')) {
            $(this).css({"padding-bottom": $(".navbar2 .bottomBar").outerHeight() + $('.logoDetails').height()})
            $('.navbar2 .bottomBar .navLinks').css({'max-height': $(".navbar2 .bottomBar .navLinks").outerHeight()})
        }
    })
    

    if (collapsed === 'false') {
        $('.navbar2').toggleClass('closed')
    }



    $($(".arrow").parent().parent().parent()).click(function(){
        if (!$('.navbar2').hasClass('closed')){
          $(this).toggleClass("showMenu")
        }
    })

    $('.navbar2 .logoDetails a').click(function(){
        $('.navbar2').toggleClass('closed')
    })

    $('.navbar2 .search a').click(function(){
        if ($('.navbar2').hasClass('closed')){
            $('.navbar2').toggleClass('closed')
        }

        $("#navBarSearch").focus();
    })

    $('#navBarSearch').on("input", function() {
        const searchedValue = $(this).val()
        $('.searchResults').empty()

        if (searchedValue != '') {
            let matches = new Array()

            $('.link').each(function(){
            const linkText = $(this).text()

            if (linkText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && jQuery.inArray(linkText.toLowerCase(), matches) === -1) {
                // if (matches.length === 0) {
                //     $('.navbar2 .navLinks li .iconLink.search').css({'margin-bottom': '0px'}) 
                // }
                matches.push(linkText.toLowerCase())
                $('.searchResults').append(`<li class="searchResultsItem"><a href='${$(this).attr('href')}'>${linkText}</a></li>`)
            }

            // if (matches.length === 0) {
            //     $('.navbar2 .navLinks li .iconLink.search').css({'margin-bottom': '10px'}) 
            // }
            })
        }
        // else {
        //     $('.navbar2 .navLinks li .iconLink.search').css({'margin-bottom': '10px'})
        // }
    })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

:root {
    --primary-color: #11101d;
    --secondary-color: #1d1b31;
    --text-color: #f6f1d1; 
    --hoverBG-color: #f6f1d1;
    --hoverTX-color: #11101d;
}

.navbar2 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 260px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 10000;
} 

.navbar2.closed,
.navbar2.closed .bottomBar {
    width: 76px;
}

.navbar2 .logoDetails {
    padding-top: 15px;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar2 .logoDetails a {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 76px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2 .logoDetails a.collapseIcon {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 76px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2 .logoDetails a.collapseIcon:hover {
    background: var(--hoverBG-color);
    color: var(--hoverTX-color);
}

.navbar2 .logoDetails .logoName {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 900;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar2.closed .logoDetails .logoName {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks {
    background: var(--primary-color);
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-inline-start: 0px!important;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks {
    overflow: visible;
}

.navbar2 .bottomBar .navLinks {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li input {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    padding-left: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--text-color); 
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li input {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .fa-search {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li .fa-search:hover {
    background: var(--hoverBG-color);
    color: var(--hoverTX-color);
}

.navbar2 .navLinks ul.searchResults {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks ul.searchResults .searchResultsItem {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: var(--hoverBG-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--hoverTX-color);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}


.navbar2 .navLinks ul.searchResults .searchResultsItem a {
    color: var(--hoverTX-color);
}

.navbar2 .navLinks ul.searchResults .searchResultsItem:hover {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--hoverBG-color);
}

.navbar2 .navLinks ul.searchResults .searchResultsItem:hover a {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks ul.searchResults,
.navbar2.closed .navLinks ul.searchResults .searchResultsItem {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li:hover {
    background: var(--secondary-color);
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .iconLink {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .iconLink.search {
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li i {
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 76px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li.showMenu i.arrow {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks i.arrow {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .linkName {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .subMenu {
    padding-inline-start: 0px;
    padding: 6px 0px 0px 76px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    display: none;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .subMenu li {
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li.showMenu .subMenu {
    display: block;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .subMenu a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8.8px 0;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .subMenu a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li a .linkName {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li .subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 3.8px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li:hover .subMenu {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto; 
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .subMenu .linkName {
    display: none;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li .subMenu .linkName {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li .subMenu.blank .linkName {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar2 .navLinks li .subMenu.blank {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.navbar2.closed .navLinks li:hover .subMenu.blank {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block;
}

.navbar2 .bottomBar {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--text-color);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 260px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.mainSection {
    position: relative;
    left: 260px;
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar2.closed ~ .mainSection {
    left: 76px;
    width: calc(100% - 76px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar2 closed">
      <div class="logoDetails">
        <a href="#" class="collapseIcon"><i class="bi bi-list"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="logoName">
          Test
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="navLinks">
        <li>
          <div class="iconLink search">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
            <input id="navBarSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
          </div>
          <ul class="searchResults">
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="iconLink">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
              <span class="linkName">Test1</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></a>
          </div>
          <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a class="linkName" href="#">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#">Test1.1</a></li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#">Test1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="iconLink">
            <a href="#"><i class="bi bi-globe"></i><span class="linkName">Test2</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></a>
          </div>
          <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a class="linkName" href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#">Test2.1</a></li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#">Test2.2</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="bottomBar">
        <ul class="navLinks">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-bug"></i>
              <span class="linkName">Report an issue</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="subMenu blank">
              <li><a class="linkName" href="#">Report an issue</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fas fa-hammer"></i>
              <span class="linkName">Feature request</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="subMenu blank">
              <li><a class="linkName" href="#">Feature request</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="mode">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
                <span class="linkName">Dark mode</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="subMenu blank">
                <li>
                <a class="linkName" href="#">Dark mode</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely missed it. Setting `transition: 0s;` for `.navbar2.closed .navLinks li .subMenu` and then setting `transition: all 0.5s ease;` for `.navbar2.closed .navLinks li:hover .subMenu` fixed the issue.